# Error al actualizar vista después del login en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, login, promesas

Estoy haciendo un módulo de usuarios en Angular JS. Al momento de hacer un login equivocado, quiero mostrar una alerta de Bootstrap que diga que la contraseña o usuario están equivocadas.

El mensaje llega hasta el controller de angular pero no actualiza la vista. Ya intente con la funcion `$apply`, pero arroja un error que dice apply ya esta en ejecución.

Aquí muestro el Controller:

```
angular.module("login") 
    .controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,LocalStore,jwtHelper,$location,authFactory){

        $scope.jwt = LocalStore.getJWT();
        $scope.error;

        if(authFactory.isLogIn()){
            $location.path("/home");
        }

        $scope.logIn = function(user){
            authFactory.logIn(user);
            $scope.error = authFactory.getError();

        };

        $scope.logOut = function(){
            console.log($scope.error);
            $scope.error = authFactory.getError();
        };

    });
```

A continuación muestro el Factory que hice para validar los logins

```
.factory("authFactory", function($http, LocalStore, $location, jwtHelper){

var authFactory = {};
    authFactory.errores="-";

    authFactory.logIn = function(user){
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                skipAuthorization: true,
                url: 'login.php',
                data: { op:'login', username: user.username, password: user.password } ,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("Entrando al success");
            if('jwt' in response.data){
                console.log("Login Exitoso");
                LocalStore.saveJWT(response.data.jwt);
            }else if('error' in response.data){
                console.log("Login Erroneo");
                authFactory.errores = response.data.error;
                console.log("Imprimiendo authFactory: " + authFactory.errores);
            };
            if(authFactory.isLogIn){
                $location.path("/home");
            }else{
                $location.path("/login");
            }
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Login Fallido jajajajaj");
      });


    };

    authFactory.getError=function(){
        console.log("Obteniendo AuthFactory en get Error: "+ authFactory.errores);
        return authFactory.errores;
    };
```

Este es el template del login:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" ng-show="error">
            <strong>Well done!</strong> {{error}}.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control form-group">
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large form-group" ng-click="logIn(user)">Log In</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el login es una función asincrónica (utiliza ajax) por lo que estas enviando la petición e intentando recoger los errores resultantes al mismo tiempo. La solución mas sencilla es retornar una promesa y recoger los errores luego de que esta se haya terminado.

Cambia tu función `authFactory.logIn` a esto

```
authFactory.logIn = function(user){
    // al retornar la llamada a la función estas devolviendo un promise implicitamente
    return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            skipAuthorization: true,
            url: 'login.php',
            data: { op:'login', username: user.username, password: user.password } ,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("Entrando al success");
        // manejas primero el error
        if ('error' in response.data) {
            console.log("Login Erroneo");
            // retornas una promesa rechazada
            return $q.reject(response.data);
        }
        // Si no ocurrieron errores la petición es satisfactoria
        console.log("Login Exitoso");
        LocalStore.saveJWT(response.data.jwt);

        if(authFactory.isLogIn){
            $location.path("/home");
        }else{
            $location.path("/login");
        }
        // Retornas el token para encadenar un then
        return response.data.jwt;
  }).catch(function errorCallback(response) {
     console.log("Login Fallido jajajajaj");
     // Retornas el contenido del error
     return $q.reject(response.data.error || response.data);
  });
};
```

y luego en tu controller haces esto

```
$scope.logIn = function(user){
    authFactory.logIn(user).then(function() {
        // aquí pones lo que quieras
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // aquí manejas el error
        // ya el método authFactory.getError() sobra
        $scope.error = error;
    });
};
```

También puedes hacer

```
$scope.logIn = function(user){
    // ya que el factory lo hace todo no es necesario un método then, solo recoger el error
    authFactory.logIn(user).catch(function(error) {
        // aquí manejas el error
        $scope.error = error;
    });
};
```

Para que esto funcione debes inyectar `$q` como dependencia porque uso `$q.reject` en una parte del código del Factory

No uses `then(successFn, errorFn)` en su lugar usa `then(successFn).catch(errorFn)`, el primero es un [anti patrón](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-.then).

Debes retornar algo (`return [objeto]`) en el cuerpo del `then` o el `catch` para seguir encadenando, de lo contrario JavaScript retornará `return undefined;` automáticamente por ti.

Comment: He hecho una reversión ya que el código lo debería editar devconcept. Dejo el comentario para que lo vea y lo edite.

Comment: @MiquelColl Gracias. La edición es de hecho un error ya que una vez que se entra en el canal del `catch` la promesa está rechazada y no hay necesidad de rechazarla de nuevo. Con poner otro `catch` handler es suficiente.

Comment: Sorry.. :P soy novato en esto de stackoverflow.... amm.. como pondría ese otro catch handler... se pondría en el controller??

Comment: @HiramHernandez Tienes razón en la edición, no había revisado bien. Cuando leí la respuesta confundí lo que ponías con un [catch](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) filtrado. Diferentes librerías implementan los métodos de formas diferentes y `$q` no es conocida precisamente por ser una librería completa. Edición corregida.